# What is the ideal data structure for 2D and 3D graphics in WebGL or Metal?

Tags: architecture, data-structures, graphics, opengl

I have been thinking about this here and there for several years but haven't gotten around to having the time to actually implement it. I am getting closer to being able to implement a graphics renderer like [Pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js) or [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), but would like to know first what the ideal data structure is (in the case of 2D and 3D engines, separately or together) for for storing the graphics so that you can most optimally pipe them through WebGL or Metal (from Apple) rendering pipelines.

The way I see it, for 2D at least, is that you have these key attributes:

- x
- y
- red
- blue
- green
- alpha

If you create a bit buffer containing let's say 32-bit integers in struct containing these 6 items, you have essentially a chain of 32-bit integers for each struct/point, one after the other, in a giant array. This is ideal I know for WebGL because you can simply bind your buffer/bitarray to the WebGL pipeline without any memory copying or transferring or anything, and all be done in parallel on the GPU. The array would look like this essentially:

```
<x><y><red><blue><green><alpha><x><y><red><blue><green><alpha>...<x><y><red><blue><green><alpha>...
```

For 3D I *think* it would take just this, but I'm not entirely sure, haven't spent too much time on 3D.

- x
- y
- z
- w (for the matrix operations something?)
- red
- blue
- green
- alpha

But is that correct? For both 2D and 3D, are there any other attributes that you could use to add to this basic struct to pipe into WebGL/Metal to handle more advanced cases you might run into? Is it better to have separate arrays? What about things like physics (temperature/heat, gravity/velocity/acceleration, friction, springiness, etc.), can they be added to this basic struct for use in the WebGL pipeline to make things most **optimal** (lack of memory copying around, essentially)?

I would basically like to know, for any type of rendering, what the struct would look like that you would pass to the WebGL/Metal engine for optimal performance and maximum feature set.

Currently, I am wondering about how to replicate HTML in WebGL, so wondering about rendering rectangles and text essentially. But ideally I would like to also start considering 3D objects, particle systems, and complex paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline can be customized to what you need. I don't think there is an optimal set vertex attributes without a clear idea of what you need.

My suggestion is to start simple and add as you need. It is much easier to start with a simple system that works and evolve it, than it is to start with a complex system that works.

For starters, you will likely want texture coordinates. And you will have to think about how many textures are you going to use, and if you need different coordinate for each one.

Another use of attributes is to lookup in uniform arrays. For example, you could define different attributes for different materials, upload them as a uniform array, and then use an attribute to lookup the materials.

The realm of things you could do with vertex and fragment shaders is vast. Much more if we consider rendering to a texture, and using that as input for another render step (e.g. post-processing). I will not attempt to enumerate all the things. However, you might be interested in ray tracing and physically based rendering.

Let us see your list instead:

- temperature/heat. Perhaps. One of the things that could be added is the color of light the object emits (not just what color it reflects), another idea is to add a temperature in kelvin and simulate black body radiation.
- gravity/velocity/acceleration. For a post-process step, where you do motion blur, some idea of the velocity would be useful. There is also the idea to doing simple physics in GPU. *I think gravity should be an uniform. I do not think gravity will be different from a vertex to another. You also need to think how are you going to divide your draw calls.*
- friction, springiness, etc. Very unlikely you will work with these in GPU. *Oh, I can think of something you could model with drag and elasticity: grass waving in the wind, computed in a vertex shader.*

*For any animation to happen in the GPU (physics based or not), you want to pass time as an uniform. Please don't make time a vertex attribute.*

However, you said you want to do something like HTML in GPU. *Why do you want friction and stuff?* Requirements are paramount. Add the attributes you need, nothing more.

Think how values change:

- The value can change from a pixel (fragment) to the next in a non-continous way? Use a texture, and add texture coordinates as attributes.
- The value can change from a vertex to another, perhaps it is interpolated between them? Use a vertex attribute.
- There will be many vertex with the same values but there will be different in a single call? Use vertex attribute for lookup in a uniform array.
- The value will be the same for everything in the draw call, but it might change from draw call to the next? Use an uniform.
- The value stays the same during the lifetime of the application or changes very rarely? Inline the value in the shader program. It is a literal constant. *Remember you can change shader programs, and you may generate the shader code based on user configuration. You just don't want to compile them often.*
- The values are decided in a prior render step? Use a texture. You might be interested in Deferred Shading.
- The values change spatially? That is, the value will be different for each vertex or set of vertex, depending on where they are in space. Use a texture. Except, this time you lookup in the texture based on vertex (or fragment) coordinates. *You could do something similar with cube mapping and direction instead of position.* (also works relative to the camera).

Given that you can have multiple shader programs, and do multiple draw calls per frame… It might make sense to separate objects that require a different set of vertex attributes in different draw calls, with different shader programs. It might not, depending on what you are doing.

See also [Approaching Zero Driver Overhead in OpenGL (Presented by NVIDIA)](https://gdcvault.com/play/1020791/).